# How do I enable index downloads in Eclipse for Maven dependency search?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am using Eclipse Luna with the m2e plug-in. When I search for dependencies, I get the following warning (also see the screenshot after):

> Index downloads are disabled, search result may be incomplete.

[image]

How can I enable index downloads?

Answer (score 384, accepted):

1. In Eclipse, click on **Windows > Preferences**, and then choose **Maven** in the left side.
2. Check the box "**Download repository index updates on startup**".

   - Optionally, check the boxes **Download Artifact Sources** and **Download Artifact JavaDoc**.
3. Click **OK**. The warning won't appear anymore.
4. Restart Eclipse.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/IJ2T3vc.png]

Comment: dude it taking long time :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012567/why-does-eclipse-take-so-long-to-update-maven-dependencies will fix it.A fresh index offers you an up to date list of dependencies, e.g. in the Add Dependency dialog. But I found it will do if the index is updated manually (as needed) in the Maven Repositories View.

Answer (score 94):

Tick 'Full Index Enabled' and then 'Rebuild Index' of the central repository in 'Global Repositories' under `Window > Show View > Other > Maven > Maven Repositories`, and it should work.

The rebuilding may take a long time depending on the speed of your internet connection, but eventually it works.

Comment: BTW: Press: ctrl+3: (opens a dialog to search for views) and then start typing "Maven Repositories" - is much faster then clicking: Window > Show View > Other > Maven > Maven Repositories

Comment: This added 4GB and growing till I stopped it, to my computer, I do not recommend this method.

Comment: For reference, I did this method and it finished at 5.8gB.

Comment: On right click on Global Repository the "rebuild index" is not there - any idea how to get it?