# Java - install Spring from maven

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc

I Have started to learn on springs recently and I am stuck at the very beginning.
in the tutorial that I follow on youtube it says that i have to install maven and from maven i can install spring,
i have installed maven and now i want to install Spring framework from it.
it sounds pretty simple. As i understand, maven searches for the spring framework from its repositories and downloads.

I have referred these two links - [First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24252256/how-do-i-enable-index-downloads-in-eclipse-for-maven-dependency-search) and [Second](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/quot-Updating-Maven-Dependencies-quot-td138514.html)

But when i try to search for dependencies, i dont see any dependencies dispalyed to me when i search for "springframework" as shown in the tutorial.

everywhere i google, they say the maven indexes have to be updated on startup, the update process starts when i start eclipse , but its not finishing/ending.

This is my pom.xml file,

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.caveofprogramming.spring.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>testprog</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>testprog</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: have you the same problem out of eclipse (by mvn command) ?

Comment: i am running this on windows, so not tried in command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this to your dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i tried adding, it downloaded the spring jars but in pom.xml i have an error now - 
"Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Failure to transfer org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local 
  repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact"
this is at the line - xsi:schemaLocation=

Comment: try to execute: 
 mvn clean install

Comment: where should i execute this?? i am not using command line, i am working on windows

Comment: right click on the project  > run as > Maven clean and then maven install

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple. For starting out, your pom.xml file should have these directories (This is for maven):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

these should be under the

so in the end your pom.xml should look like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>qwe</groupId>
  <artifactId>qwe</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/main/test</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies><dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency><dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency></dependencies>

</project>
```

Subsequently you should right click your maven project > run > run as > maven install and it should  install properly. email me at thenwb3@gmail.com if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

`Spring` is a huge framework and it depends which parts of it do you need. For example, for `spring-context` specify the following dependency in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

For `spring-core`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

For `spring-web`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And so on. I recommend you to use [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/tags/spring) where you can find any `Spring` dependency you need. Some of the dependencies already include another, for example, with `spring-mvc` you already get `spring-core`, `spring-context`, `string-web` and some others.

So, try to add those dependencies and then execute the `Maven` command:

`mvn clean install`

This should download all the dependencies and put them to your local repository. If this will not work, try to use `-U` parameter like this

`mvn clean install -U`