# Eclipse is not really helpful with maven dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependency-management

Whenever I'd like to check whether some dependencies of my project have newer versions, at the end I allways find myself googling after it. My problem is independent from the given version of Eclipse, it's been presense since I use this IDE.

I have the naive (natural?) expectation that the content assist in the POM editor would list **ALL** available versions, but it only lists the ones already existing in my .m2 folder. Google didn't help me, found no answers either here. Neither playing around with settings did the trick.

Could anyone give me a hint at least on a proper search string?

**EDIT**

Index download is enabled.
Under 'googling' above I meant searching maven.org. After scrambling the proxy settings, maven log contained lines like

```
!MESSAGE Unable to update index for central|https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
```

That gave me the ultimate idea where to search.

I have no idea where the index is stored on my computer, but the fact that https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 is somehow processed implies that my Eclipse *should* know about all versions, but keeps its secrets.

Comment: Searching for artifacts I strongly recommend https://search.maven.org/ Also you should enable to download the index of central see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24252256/how-do-i-enable-index-downloads-in-eclipse-for-maven-dependency-search

Comment: Ich use `mvn coordinates artifaktname`

Comment: When using the POM snippets proposed by https://mvnrepository.com which starts with a comment that contains a link, you can just Ctrl+click that link. It should also not be too difficult to create a Jenkins job or something similar that checks `pom.xml` files for new dependencies versions.

Comment: You can also use the Maven goal https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/display-dependency-updates-mojo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following to check dependencies for available new versions:

1. **Right-click** the **`pom.xml`** file and choose ***Run As > Maven Build...***
2. In the *Edit Configuration* dialog enter into the field ***Goals:* `versions:display-dependency-updates`**
3. Click ***Run***

This will run a Maven build that prompts in the *Console* view something similar like the following:

```
...
[INFO] The following dependencies in Dependencies have newer versions:
[INFO]   com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core .............. 2.9.0 -> 2.10.1
[INFO]   net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE ............................. 9.9.1-2 -> 9.9.1-6
[INFO]   org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit ...
[INFO]                             4.9.0.201710071750-r -> 5.5.1.201910021850-r
[INFO]   org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api ................ 5.1.0 -> 5.6.0-M1
[INFO]   org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine ............. 5.1.0 -> 5.6.0-M1
[INFO]   org.slf4j:slf4j-simple ........................ 1.7.20 -> 2.0.0-alpha1
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 16.936 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-09T13:59:37+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It is also recommended having a comment with a link at the beginning of each dependency which can be opened via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click or via <kbd>F3</kbd>:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Though it is better a workaround of the actual problem, this approach can save some time upon updating dependencies and plugins.

Comment: @hurjup You might report a feature request or - event better - propose a patch to Eclipse m2e (but keep in mind querying the versions takes time and there might not always be an internet connection). Alternatively or in addition, you could do a cron job that will let you know when new versions are available (for example with Jenkins).