# Why does STS take so long to update Maven dependencies?

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I have a Maven project in my STS workspace. When I start STS, it takes a very long time to update Maven dependencies. It actually seems like it will never finish and while it is doing this update, I can't do anything in STS.I am working under LAN and firewall connection is this problem?

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Do you have the same problem when running Maven on the command line?

Comment: no maven commands working fine in cmd

Comment: transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.8.RELEASE from/to remote-repo-repo1.maven.repository.redhat-remote-cache (https://oneartifactory.verizon.com/artifactory/maven.repository.redhat-remote-cache/): connect timed out and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM

Comment: i am getting above error on top of <parent> tag

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012567/why-does-eclipse-take-so-long-to-update-maven-dependencies